# How to include 3rd party npm module without npm install?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I need to use a 3rd party npm module, it's very old, I cannot directly use it with `npm i` and `reqiure`, I have to modify some source code of this npm module for my special use case.

So I'm thinking to clone the source code of the npm module to my source code base, and use it directly.

As the npm module is not a pure JS module, it contains some C code. I have no idea how to do this.

Could you give me some guidance?

For example, let's say the 3rd party npm module is `request`, so generally I just `npm i --save request` and then in my code I can use it like this

```
const request = require('request');
```

Since what I want is to modify some request code, so I will download request source code from `https://github.com/request/request`, and maybe put the `lib` folder into my project's root.

Then how can use `request` from this `lib` folder?

2. let's say this `request` includes some `c` code, how can I use it from `lib` again?

Comment: For `C` code, checkout Native API https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html

Comment: Please help me compile some unknown code? Hmm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install from a local folder where you have done the modifications

```
npm install /path-to-local-folder
```

To get this into package.json use

```
   "dependencies":
  {
    "mymodule": "file:./path-to-folder",
    "request": "^2.5"
  }
```

Comment: So if I send the source code along with the 3rd party module resides in `lib` and the package.json, other's can just use it?

Comment: Theoretically, yes. I do recommend, however creating an npm package.
Change the request source code's package name @garen96/request or something (github username) and publish it and then use it 

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-create-and-publish-your-npm-package-node-module-in-just-10-minutes-b8ca3a100050

Comment: Thank you, and what if it's a `c` code npm package, I can do it the same way?

Comment: slightly more complicated  https://sunzhongkui.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/create-and-publish-node-js-c-addon/

Comment: Thanks for the link, let me try and get back later